# Fixed width column and fluid content area in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Twitter Bootstrap to mix fixed and fluid width columns, [exactly like this](http://jsfiddle.net/JANJB/1/).

As you can see, it is trivially easy to do with HTML and CSS. Is there a way to do it using bootstrap only?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way in Bootstrap to prevent from fluid style. You have to write new class and use it in the same div.

```
<div class="span4 newclass">

.newclass{width:200px!important}
```

Comment: <div class="span4 span-fixed">  with  .span-fixed {width: 245px;}

Comment: This will break the other columns, since they are based on percentages.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a span that contains a fixed-width column absolutely positioned to the left or to the right and then add another column with a margin wide enough to fit the fixed column.